# pass vs. make the rounds

Tags: verbs, idioms, phrasal-verbs

Original: Uncle Jan passed in the yard bellow, making the rounds.

Although I know what making the rounds means, in fact, considering the sentence, I am wondering what is the difference between the followings?d'oh!

pass

make the rounds

make the rounds also do the rounds
1. to be passed from person to person The rumor making the rounds in Washington is that the ambassador will be leaving.
2. to go from place to place Tony and I made the rounds of the cheap bars in the city. Every new executive must do the rounds of all the departments in the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example sentence, I think that adding a few words might make it clearer.

*"Uncle Jan passed by in the yard below me, making the rounds."* He was in the process of "making the rounds" as he passed the observer.

Another example, "The executive passed my office when she made the rounds to introduce herself to the managers of the department across the hall."